# Obtaining the $L^p$ norm of a function via testing against $L^{p'}$ functions.

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, duality-theorems

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ be a locally integrable function and let $p\in[1,+\infty)$ and $p'\in(1,+\infty]$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p'}=1$. Denoting by $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the set of infinitely differentiable functions of compact support, I proved via extension by continuity and density of a bounded linear operator, Riesz representation theorem and Hölder inequality that:

$$\|f\|_p=\sup_{\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n),\\ \|\varphi\|_{p'}=1} \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\varphi(x)\operatorname{d}x\right|$$
without assuming a prior knowledge of the fact that $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (i.e. if $f\notin L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then RHS makes sense and it is equal to $+\infty$).

What if we remove the locally integrable hypothesis? I see that then we can't take the $\sup$ over all $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in general, because for some $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ it could very well happen that the integral of $f\varphi$ is not well defined at all. So I thought that maybe if we take the $\sup$ over all $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\varphi f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then what we obtain is again $\|f\|_p$. However, I didn't find a way to prove or disprove such a claim. So:

> If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ is a measurable function (not necessarily locally integrable), is it true that $$\|f\|_p=\sup_{\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n),\\ \|\varphi\|_{p'}=1, \\ f\varphi\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}  \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\varphi(x)\operatorname{d}x\right| ?$$

Comment: Consider $f_n = f\mathbf{1}_{|f| \leq n}$ and $\varphi_n \in \mathscr{K}^\infty(\mathbf{R}^d)$ with $\|f_n\|_p \leq \left| \int\limits_{\mathbf{R}^d} f_n \varphi_n \right| + \dfrac{1}{n}.$

Comment: How can we deduce that $f\varphi_n\in L^1$? Counterexample: $f(x):=1/{x^2}$ and if you don't assume any other restriction on $\varphi_n$ then $f\varphi_n\notin L^1$

Comment: If your function isn't locally integrable, wouldn't that mean there is some compact $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\int_K |f(x)| dx = \infty$? By Hölder inequality, this means that your $p$-norm is already infinite. Or am I misunderstanding.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know in principle if it is true or not that the function is locally integrable. I'm guessing if that formula, that has a meaning in both cases, gives the correct result.

Comment: @Bob I do not know why you want $f \varphi_n$ integrable since $\|f\|_p = \infty.$ So, you can divide $f = f\mathbf{1}_{|f| \leq n} + f\mathbf{1}_{|f| > n} = f_n + r_n$ and then $\|f \varphi_n\|_1 \geq \|f_n \varphi_n\|_1$ and the right hand side converges to $\|f\|_p = \infty,$ so indeed $\|f\|_p = \sup_\varphi \|f \varphi\|_{p'},$ where $\varphi$ runs on $\mathscr{K}^\infty(\mathbf{R}^d).$ You can also have $\|\varphi\|_{p'} = 1$ by multiplication by a constant. As to whether or not $f \varphi$ is integrable, as said above, just why? It makes no sense.

Comment: the integral could be very well not defined as an element of $[-\infty,+\infty]$ at all, because the integrand could assume very large positive and very large negative values. And this if you assume that the integrand is real valued. If f is complex valued, the situation is even worse.

Comment: The norm is well-defined regardless of real or complex and I already showed you that the statement is true. As to whether you want $f \varphi$ is beyond my comprehension.

Comment: Feel free to downvote if you don't see the point. Have a good day

Comment: I never down vote, ever. Not even when the OP doesn't even know what OP is asking.

Comment: @WillM. The inequality you have, $||f\varphi_n||_1 \geq ||f_n\varphi_n||_1$ has the norm in the RHS, which is not exactly the RHS of the identity Bob has. For Bob's identity, the integration inside the absolute value of the RHS might not even exist.

Comment: Ok. I think I get the question, now. You are trying to make a sensible adjustment to the RHS of the first identity, to see whether or not you can find a sequence (or a net) of finite values $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f\varphi_k < \infty$ such that $\lim_{k\to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f\varphi_k = ||f||_p$. This would be surely the case when $f$ is locally integrable (as you have explained). But we don't know what happens otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the function $f$ is measurable, which (as you clearly know) a little more general than $L^1_{\text{loc}}$-integrablity. I will assume that $f \geq 0$ too.  So, we can use *Lebesgue integral*, which is defined as $ \int_{\Omega} f \,\, dx = \sup_{\phi \text{ is simple}} \sum_{i=1}^N a_i |E_i|$, $\,\,$ where $a_i$ is the value of $\phi$ for every $x\in E_i$, and the $E_i$'s are disjoint sets whose union, $\,\,\cup_{i=1}^N E_i = \Omega. \,$

Now, we have two cases:

**Case 1**: $\,\,f \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$, which is equivalent to saying that $\int_{K} f \,\, dx < \infty$ for every compact subset $K \subset \Omega$. This, I understand, is the case you have already discussed, and the formula works perfectly well.

**Case 2**: $\,\,f \notin L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$, which is to say that there is some compact subset $K \subset \Omega$ such that $\int_{K} f \,\, dx = \infty$. If this is the case, this means $\infty = \int_k f \,\,dx \leq \left(\int_K f^{p}\, \, dx\right)^{1/p} \underbrace{\left(\int_K 1 \, \, dx\right)^{1/p'}}_{\text{finite}}$. So, we already know that $||f||_p = \infty$. The problem is whether or not the formula will correctly depict the situation. I believe it does, which I argue as follows.

Let $K$ be the compact set above. Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and cover $K$ with the balls $B_{\delta(x)}(x)$ for $x \in K$, where $\frac{1}{N}>\delta(x) > 0$  are small enough for the balls to stay inside $\Omega$. Then, there is a finite subcollection $\{B_{\delta(x_1)}(x_1), ...,B_{\delta(x_k)}(x_k)\}$ that cover $K$. So, one of these balls --say, $B_{\delta(x_1)}(x_1)$-- satisfies $\int_{B_{\delta(x_1)}(x_1)} f \,\, dx =\infty$; otherwise, $\int_K f \,\, dx < \infty$. Take a smooth cutoff function, $0 \leq \xi_\epsilon\leq 1$, such that $\xi_\epsilon \equiv 1$ on $B_\delta = B_{\delta(x_1)}(x_1)$ and  $\xi_\epsilon \equiv 0$ *outside* $B_{(1+\epsilon)\delta} = B_{(1+\epsilon)\delta(x_1)}(x_1)$. And set $c_\epsilon$ so that $\left(\int_{B_{(1+\epsilon)\delta}} (c_\epsilon \xi_\epsilon)^{p'}\,\,dx\right)^{1/p'} = 1$. Then, we have that $\int_{\Omega}f (c_\epsilon \xi_\epsilon)\,\,dx \geq c_\epsilon \int_{B_{\delta}} f\,\, dx = \infty$. So, the formula works as well.

$\,$

P.S. I apologize for the messiness.

$\,$
$\,$

**Edit**: I just saw your latest comment. I am not sure if the formula still work when $f$ has both negative and positive values, but I think it is possible.